# Exprimer une "recommandation conditionnelle" ou "recommandation différentielle"

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

### Contexte : le verbe "préconiser" et la différence avec "recommander".

Il me semblait que préconiser était associé à une démarche de ce que j’appellerai une "recommandation conditionnelle" ou "recommandation différentielle", (définition ci-après). Cependant, le wiktionnaire ne confirme pas: [préconiser — Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A9coniser) et le mot "préconiser" apparaît presque comme un simple synonyme de "recommander".

### "Recommandation conditionnelle" ou "recommandation différentielle" (je ne sais pas s'il existe déjà une expression pour cela)

C'est une situation qu'on trouve notamment quand on fait appel à un conseil.  Le conseil peut vous recommander de faire ou de ne pas faire une action, et de façon complètement décorrélée, vous éclairer sur les options désirables ou non dans le cas où vous le faites.

On peut exprimer une "recommandation conditionnelle" ou "recommandation différentielle" de façon un peu formelle ainsi, avec A B et C des "variables" :

- "il est question que vous fassiez A"
- "je ne vous recommande pas de faire A et je ne vous recommande pas de ne pas faire A, ce n'est pas mon propos"
- "si vous décidez de faire A (qui est donc purement votre choix sans influence de ma part), je vous ( incite à / recommande de / etc ) le faire de la façon B plutôt que de la façon C (parce que B a telles conséquences prévisibles alors que C telles autres).

### Question

Existe-t-il une façon simple d'exprimer cela ?

- Le simple emploi de "je vous recommande B" peut sembler encourager à faire A.
- Le simple emploi de "je vous mets en en garde par rapport à l'option C" peut sembler inciter à ne pas faire A.

Du coup, je ne vois pas plus simple que : "si vous choisissez de faire A, point sur lequel je n'ai pas de recommandation ni pour ni contre, je vous recommande la façon B et vous met en garde contre la façon C".

Existe-t-il un verbe ou une construction plus simple qui exprime cette idée sans une périphrase dédiée ?
Certains synonymes de "recommander" vont-ils dans ce sens ?

Answer (score 1):

> Je vous engage à opter pour la façon B *si jamais* vous choississez A.

Ce qui veut dire « moi à votre place, j'aurai choisi la façon B si vous avez choisi A » tout en pensant que le conseil donné doit être avisé.

Remarques : [la synonymie](https://cnrtl.fr/synonymie/recommander) entre « recommander » et « engager » n'est pas évidente de façon générale. Les définitions sont plus précises et complètes dans un véritable dictionnaire de langue.

Answer (score 1):

Il pourrait être utile de rectifier tout d'abord la définition du Wiktionnaire, ou tout au moins de suggérer qu'un ajustement de celle-ci n'est pas exclu en précisant que le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9coniser) considère le verbe « préconiser » comme ayant un sens plus fort que celui de « recommander ».

> B. Mod. Recommander vivement et avec insistance quelque chose (à quelqu'un). Synon. prôner.

Sans rentrer dans des détails on comprend que l'idée est essentiellement celle de *conseil* ou *conseil technique*.

Si on cherche à rendre la formulation plus explicite dans le sens des « spécifications » demandées rien ne vient à l'esprit facilement.
Il ne me semble pas qu'il existe un terme d'un seul mot pour ce concept. Considérant ce qu'il incombe de faire à la personne chargée de telles recommandations, il est clair qu'elle doit d'abord faire un certain travail d'information dont la personne qui cherche les recommandations doit être le récepteur. En possession de cette information, cette dernière pourra alors faire ce qui a été appelé depuis seulement les années 40 du siècle dernier « un *choix informé* » ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=choix+inform%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchoix%20inform%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cchoix%20inform%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0)). Comme le terme est nouveau et qu'il a commencé a devenir important  dans les années 80, il est apparent qu'il remplit un vide, que rien d'autre ne le remplace. La personne chargée des recommandations ayant donc d'abord à préparer quelqu'un à faire un choix informé, ses recommandations dans le domaine de cette information pourraient être appelée « *recommandations de choix informé* ».

On trouve par exemple 4 sources récentes qui parlent de *promouvoir un choix informé*.

- Journal International de Bioéthique - Volume 8 - Page 158 -  1997
- L'éthique de la recherche: guide pour le chercheur en ... - Page 251 Hubert Doucet - 2002
- Les hygiénistes: enjeux, modèles et pratiques, XVIIIe-XXe ... - Page 336 Patrice Bourdelais - 2001 - ‎
- Laval théologique et philosophique - Volume 54 - Page 279 - 1998 -

Ce concept correspond en fait exactement à l'activité envisagée et il est exprimé de façon plus juste que par « recommander un choix informé », étant donné que l'on ne comprend pas d'emblée que ce qui est recommandé ce n'est pas de choisir mais c'est ce qui permet de faire un choix ; il est apparent que l'on peut parler de « *promotion de choix informé* » et pourquoi pas, de « *promoteur de choix informé* ».  Évidemment on pense tout de suite au  terme traditionnel qui est « *conseiller* » ou « *conseiller technique* » et on peut se demander pourquoi rechigner à l'employer en faveur d'un terme qui peut donner l'impression d'être long ou même pompeux, si ce n'est qu'il n'insiste pas sur l'idée de préparation à un choix, bien que celle-ci soit un concept inhérent et même central à l'activité du conseiller.

« Promouvoir » est un terme qui n'a qu'un peu le sens de « recommander »: ses synonymes sont « encourager », « favoriser », « soutenir ».

En fonction de ce vocabulaire, les possibilités suivantes peuvent avoir un intérêt.

- En promotion/soutient du choix A, B est un atout mais des réserves s'imposent pour C.
- Pour un choix informé de A, pèsent dans la balance B, qui est un atout, et C, pour lequel j'ai des réserves.